# Overloading assignment operator for template class

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I am trying to overload assignment operators for two different template classes but with the same template type:

```
template <class DataType> class Foo
{
    public: Foo<data_type>& operator=(Bar<data_type> const &bar);
};
template <class DataType> class Bar
{
    public: Bar<data_type>& operator=(Foo<data_type> const &foo);
};
```

However when I try:

```
Foo<int> a;
Bar<int> b = a;
```

I get the error:

> No viable conversion from 'Foo< int >' to 'Bar< int >'.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Note that the given example fails with multiple compile errors long before it gets to the conversion issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conversions are done via copy constructors, not assignment operators. So you want to implement:

```
Bar(const Foo<data_type>& foo);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write:

```
Bar<int> b = a; // ERROR! No viable user-defined conversion sequence
```

You are *copy-initializing* object `b` from object `a`. This is **not** the same as *assigning* object `a` to an already constructed object `b`, in spite of the `=` symbol being used.

With copy-initialization, the compiler has to look for a user-defined conversion sequence that can convert `a` into an object of type `Bar<int>`, from which `b` could be eventually copy-constructed or move-constructed.

Assignment, on the other hand, would work:

```
Foo<int> a;
Bar<int> b;
b = a; // OK
```